# how to calculate the sum of digits for a number in java?

Tags: java, while-loop, sum

i have a small function that ask user to enter a positive number than give him the reverse and calculate the sum of its digits.

the first part of code work fine but the sum of digits return zero how to solve this problem ?

i know that the user input must be asked one time to be entered and not twice so how to fix this function because it do not take the user input.

## code:

```
package exam3Programing1_20_12_2010;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question3 {

    private int num;
    private int sum;
    private int reverse;


    public int fill() {

        System.out.println("enter the number");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = in.nextInt();

        if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("enter a positive number");
        }
        while (num != 0) {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("your reverse number is : " + reverse);
        return num;
    }

    public void sumDigits() {

        while (num != 0) {
            sum = sum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }

        System.out.println("sum of digits: " + sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Question3 q3 = new Question3();
        q3.fill();
        q3.sumDigits();
    }
}
```

## output

```
enter the number
1234
your reverse number is : 4321
sum of digits: 0
```

## the updated code

```
package exam3Programing1_20_12_2010;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question3 {

    private int num;
    private int sum;
    private int reverse;


    public int fill() {

        int myNumber = num;
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        myNumber = in.nextInt();

        if (myNumber < 0) {
            System.out.println("enter a positive number");
        }
        while (myNumber != 0) {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + myNumber % 10;
            myNumber = myNumber / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("your reverse number is : " + reverse);
        return num;
    }

    public void sumDigits() {

        while (num != 0) {
            sum = sum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }

        System.out.println("sum of digits: " + sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Question3 q3 = new Question3();
        q3.fill();
        q3.sumDigits();
    }
}
```

## updated output

```
enter the number
1234
your reverse number is : 4321
sum of digits: 0
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to read the integer as a string, then reverse the string and read the reversed string as an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are sharing same number in both reverse and sum method and when you first call reverse method you go on dividing the number until 0 and hence when you come to sum method, your number is 1 and hence sum is 0.

Inorder to rectify this, i would suggest you define local variable called mynumber like:

```
public int fill() {

    System.out.println("enter the number");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = in.nextInt();

    if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("enter a positive number");
    }
    int myNumber = num;  
    while (myNumber != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + myNumber % 10;
        myNumber = myNumber / 10;
    }
    System.out.println("your reverse number is : " + reverse);
    return num;
}

OUTPUT:
enter the number
1234
your reverse number is : 4321
sum of digits: 10
```

Comment: yes i know but i want is not to ask the user to enter the number again  i just need to ask him to enter it one time then i reverse the number and give the sum of its digits

Comment: you solution did not work it still the same result it give me ZERO

Comment: I got the proper output as in my answer and user don't have to input multiple times just once is enough. Share your updated code and notify.

Comment: ok i will edit my question with the updated change and can you explain why it works ?

Comment: It works because now you are not updating/chaning shared instance variable `num` in your fill method. Instead you are working on a copy of num variable in fill method and hence not impacting num variable content which is needed by your sumDigits method.

Comment: okk but it did not work for me hence i used the same code as you sugest.

Comment: You changed `myNumber = in.nextInt();

        if (myNumber < 0) {
            System.out.println("enter a positive number");
        }` I didnt mentioned we need to change there. See my code and compare it with yours. It should be exactly the same as mine.

Comment: but if i do not use the in.next () how i will get the user input and the if is just for checking if the input number is positive and still not workingg

Comment: @javadev i have updated whole fill method for you. replace just fill method and nothing else and retry.

Comment: You clearly don't have idea what you are doing. The problem is that you store the input value only to local variable `myNumber`, in the `num` field of your class remains zero. You have to store the input value in your `num` field first, then copy the value of that field into the `myNumber` local variable (`int myNumber = num;`), which you then use in the rest of your function.

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing `num` in a rather unhelpful way. Try to define local variables for methods, and use instance fields only where you need them.

Notice also that your `fill()` method returns a value that you're not using.

This suggests that you should remove your `num` field entirely. Then add a local variable `num` to your `fill()` method, and then change the signature of `sumDigits()` to take a parameter:

```
public void sumDigits(int num)
```

Now your code at the end becomes

```
Question3 q3 = new Question3();
int n = q3.fill();
q3.sumDigits(n);
```

Comment: Actually num is an instance variable and there is no need to pass num back using fill method. It's just the case where OP could create local variable and use that instead of num variable.

Comment: The suggestion to remove `num` field is in my opinion a better alternative, because the class is then stateless.

Answer (score 0):

Your `num` member initializes by reading a number and with this loop:

```
    while (num != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
```

you are calculating the `reverse`, but you modify the value of `num` in the process. After the loop, `num`'s value is 0 and later, when you try to use it, you have already lost its value. Try to do this instead:

```
    reverse = 0;
    int tempNum = num;
    while (tempNum != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + tempNum % 10;
        tempNum = tempNum / 10;
    }
```

This code initializes `reverse` with 0, stores the value of `num` as a temporary value and you modify `tempNum` in the process, thus the value of `num` is left unchanged and you can use it later.

Answer (score 0):

i have somewhat updated your code and gives correct answer:

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question3 {

```
private int num;
private int sum;
private int reverse;


public int fill() {

    System.out.println("enter the number");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = in.nextInt();

    if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("enter a positive number");
    }
    while (num != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    System.out.println("your reverse number is : " + reverse);
    return reverse;
}

public void sumDigits(int number) {
    num = number;

    while (num != 0) {
        sum = sum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }

    System.out.println("sum of digits: " + sum);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Question3 q3 = new Question3();
   int number =  q3.fill();
    q3.sumDigits(number);
}
```

}